# If one does a Bedikah of a school building on the night of the 14th does one say a Bracha?

Tags: halacha

If one does a Bedikah of a school building on the night of the 14th does one say a Bracha?

Comment: What are you checking for? General rule: assume this question will be read by other people not just today.

Comment: @DoubleAA This is a different question.  This asking, if you do it, do you say a bracha.